# Objective-C: open URL from local notification

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uilocalnotification

i need to open an URL from local notification.
I pass URL by notification.userInfo and I retrieve it by this code:

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
  NSLog(@"didReceiveLocalNotification");
  NSString *url = [notif.userInfo objectForKey:@"urlMedia"];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

}

When I click the application is opened, but the openURL don't work.
Is it not possible to open URL using local notification ?

Comment: What is the url? Is it a http?

Comment: It is http URL. The problem is not in URL, it is right....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first check to make sure that UIApplication `canOpenURL` before attempting to open it. This will also help identify what the problem might be. If UIApplication doesn't know how to handle the URL given this will return `NO`. Here is what the documentation states specifically...

> Returns whether an app can open a given URL resource.
>   This method guarantees that that if openURL: is called, another app will be launched to handle it. It does not guarantee that the full URL is valid.

Example Usage:

```
NSString *urlString = [notif.userInfo objectForKey:@"urlMedia"];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

Comment: if I try to open with openUrl method for example by clicking on a button it work.

Comment: Ok but what's the return value of `canOpenURL:` if you add it to your `application: didReceiveLocalNotification:` implementation? Does it return YES or return NO? If it returns NO then this answers your question of whether or not you can open a URL from within a local notification handler. If it returns YES but isn't opening then perhaps there is something else going on that is causing it to not open the URL.

Comment: I found others info. If I put my app in background and click on notification it work (open URL after some seconds, but it works).
If I close my app (swipe after double click on iPhone button) then the  didReceiveLocalNotification is not fired !!!

Comment: Cool, glad you were abler o figure it out. You should answer your own question and mark it as the accepted answer to make it easier for others you find this question in the future to identify what the solution is.